# Universal Google Analytics - passing an array to an event

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to find what are the names of votes which are being casted with the below code, I am unable to pass the exact value to GA.

```
 var voteTitles = ko.utils.arrayFilter(koModel.userVotes(), function (userVote) {
                return userVote.name;
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < voteTitles.length; i++) {
                // I am passing voteTitles[I], which is not giving any result


gaTracker.send('event', 'Voted For', 'click',voteTitles[i]);
            }
```

this piece is in a button click event, I can select 1 vote up to 5(max) votes, all I am trying to capture is what is the name of the vote they have voted.

can somebody please help me on this?

Comment: Can you provide Google's returned response? Error codes?

Comment: are you taken off page or is the page reloaded after the button click?

Comment: page reloads on button click event

Comment: Can you provide the full piece of code you're using? Sounds like you have a form event where you have not provided `return false;`

Comment: value needs to be a string have you tried adding 's?   send('event', 'Voted For', 'click','myvalue');